# Add custom field to sublist

Tags: netsuite

I need to add a checkbox field to the item sublist of a purchase order, can someone tell me how to do this? I can't seem to find any definitive information on how this works.

thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, got it. You go to the form that you are modifying (in this case) Purchase Orders. You go to the customize menu in the right upper corner, you select "New Column Field" and fill out the relevant type information.  Then go to customize form, for the form you are going to use. Go to the screen fields tab, select the columns sub-tab and drag the column to it's new location. That's it

Happy Hunting